# SQL - How to Output Rows that Share Same Value in Certain Column

Tags: sql

I have a problem where we have different quantities of a product that share the same price. I want to find the products that share the same price for different quantities.

E.G. We have output
Table Name: Goods

| Product | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1.99 |
| A | 10 | 1.99 |
| A | 15 | 12.99 |
| B | 5 | 3.99 |
| B | 10 | 7.99 |
| B | 15 | 3.99 |

I want a result that only shows rows where the quantity is different and the price is the same.

E.G.

| Product | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1.99 |
| A | 10 | 1.99 |
| B | 5 | 3.99 |
| B | 10 | 3.99 |

How am I able to get this output?

Answer (score 1):

Perfect example for `exists`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Goods a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Goods b
              WHERE a.Product = b.Product AND a.Price = b.Price AND a.Quantity <> b.Quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function -- it acts like a group by per row.

```
SELECT *
FROM Goods
WHERE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Price) > 1
```